# cleanest way to access this JSON value in python

Tags: python, json

```
{"type":{"value":221,"Name":"Grey"},"value":"40.6"},
{"type":{"value":222,"Name":"Orange"},"value":"40.2"},
{"type":{"value":223,"Name":"Purple"},"value":"12.2"},
```

What is the cleanest way to access the outside "value" of `"40.2"` if `"Name" == "Orange"` from this particular JSON Dictionary?

I managed to achieve this by iterating but it got messy, so any ideas how to take an external value based upon a value within the internal curly brackets

Comment: _What is the cleanest way to..._ What ways have you tried so far? Show code

Comment: this is a list of dicts so `json_data[1]["value"]` should do it

Comment: There is no other way except iteration I'm afraid

Comment: iterating over "type" 
Variable1 = ['value'] IF [type['Name'] == "Orange" else 0

but i'm looking for a way to grab it exactly without the iteration

Comment: If you have to perform many such operations, you could refactor the list of dictionaries into a dictionary mapping names to dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on Patrick Haugh's. If there is only one "Orange" in the list, you can do it this way:

```
data = [
    {"type": {"value": 221, "Name": "Grey"}, "value": "40.6"},
    {"type": {"value": 222, "Name": "Orange"}, "value": "40.2"},
    {"type": {"value": 223, "Name": "Purple"}, "value": "12.2"}
]
print next((x['value'] for x in data if x['type']['Name'] == 'Orange'), 'not found')
```

Output:

```
40.2
```

The expression `(x['value'] for x in data if x['type']['Name'] == 'Orange')` is the same as in Patrick's solution, but it is a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. The difference is the generator expression is more efficient: it will stop finding as soon as the target is found, whereas list comprehension will keep on searching until the end of the list.

The `next` function takes the above expression, get the next item. If "Orange" is not found in the list, it will return the second parameter, which is the string `'not found'`.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have a list of dictionaries

```
l = [{"type":{"value":221,"Name":"Grey"},"value":"40.6"},
     {"type":{"value":222,"Name":"Orange"},"value":"40.2"},
     {"type":{"value":223,"Name":"Purple"},"value":"12.2"}]
```

Let's assume that many names can be `Orange`.  We're going to use a list comprehension to reduce this to a list of dictionaries that have `'Name': 'Orange'` extract the value from those

```
values = [d['value'] for d in l if d['type']['Name'] == 'Orange']
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but only 1 name can be 'Orange' within the give dictionary, so I'm looking for a way to access the outside "value" if the inside "name" == "Orange"

Comment: @fbstats In that case you're not really using the right data structure.  If you want to quickly find values based on unique keys, you should be using a dictionary.  It's fairly easy to make your list of dictionaries into a dictionary mapping the `name` attributes of those dictionaries to themselves.  `dict_of_dict = {d['type']['Name']: d for d in l}`